# Issue with Datatable Initialization and Rendering in Laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, datatables

I'm encountering an issue with initializing and rendering a datatable in my Laravel web application's user list page. I'm using the Laravel framework and jQuery Datatables for this functionality. I've provided the relevant code snippet below for context. The datatable is supposed to display user data retrieved from a Laravel API endpoint. However, I'm encountering an error during the rendering process that leads to a TypeError: "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'style')".

```js
if (dt_user_table.length) {
  var dt_user = dt_user_table.DataTable({
    ajax: {
      url: '/get-user-data',
      dataSrc: ''
    },
    columns: [
      // Columns definition here...
    ],
    // Rest of the datatable configuration...
  });
}
```

Laravel API Response:

The response from the Laravel /get-user-data API endpoint is in the format mentioned in my previous message.

Error Message:

I'm encountering the following error message:

```
Query.Deferred exception: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'style')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'style')
```

I'm using Laravel as the backend framework, and jQuery Datatables for frontend data presentation.
The error seems to be related to rendering certain components within the datatable, especially related to styles.
The datatable is expected to show user information including avatars, roles, plans, and statuses.
The error appears to be originating from within the datatable's rendering process.
I've verified that the Laravel API endpoint is correctly returning the expected data in JSON format.

Comment: can you share the html example table you used too?. and completed the datatables **columns** script

Comment: Here it is https://pastebin.com/5KHUVQnv

Comment: For some additional context: the code runs without error on my local desktop, but I run into that error when I attempt to load the user's list page on my VPS.